# EMC NFS Java Client MountException

Tags: java, nfs

I am trying to get the [EMC NFS Java Client](https://github.com/EMCECS/nfs-client-java) working without success.

- I installed a NFS server on Ubuntu Bionic.
- Export the /var/nfs which I created.
- Created a mount from my Ubuntu Bionic desktop
- The mount on my desktop works (10.13.148.82:/var/nfs 392287232 210137088 162153472  57% /home/gary/var/nfs) so I made the assumption the Java client should also work.

When I try to connect using [EMC NFS Java Client](https://github.com/EMCECS/nfs-client-java) to the same server using the same export I mounted on my desktop with the following code

```
Nfs3 nfs3 = new Nfs3(hostname, export, new CredentialUnix(), 3);
```

I get the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
mount failure, server: 10.13.148.82, export: /var/nfs, nfs version: 3, returned state: 13
com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.mount.MountException: mount failure, server: 10.13.148.82, export: /var/nfs, nfs version: 3, returned state: 13
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.lookupRootHandle(Nfs3.java:342)
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.prepareRootFhAndNfsPort(Nfs3.java:311)
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.<init>(Nfs3.java:258)
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.<init>(Nfs3.java:201)
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3.<init>(Nfs3.java:228)
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.io.FileReadingTest.testReading(FileReadingTest.java:104)
    at com.emc.ecs.nfsclient.nfs.io.FileReadingTest.main(FileReadingTest.java:53)
```

The error message is not very helpfull and I don't know where to even begin looking for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your /etc/exports file content should add insecure option,for example
/data    10.16.150.0/24(rw,sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)